# How to use backup with triggers in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table (Cycle) and I created a trigger

```
alter trigger AnyName on Cycles
for insert,update,delete
AS
BACKUP DATABASE medrepcrm TO  DISK = N'C:\medrepcrm.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'pcrm-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

But when I insert, update, or delete in the Cycle table that leads to an error.

```
Msg 3021, Level 16, State 0, Procedure AnyName, Line 8
Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AnyName, Line 8
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
The statement has been terminated.
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Why are you trying to perform a backup inside a trigger? (If we understand the motivation we can probably suggest an alternative)

Comment: I'm surprised the BACKUP command is even valid inside a trigger!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BACKUP DATABASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) on MSDN says

> The BACKUP statement is not allowed in an explicit or implicit transaction.

A trigger is *always* in a transactions

If you work it through, a backup which is transactionally consistent snapshot of a database: it doesn't make sense for it to be in it's own transaction.

Not least, on RESTORE  the roll forward/roll back mechanism would have to rollback the transaction containing the backup... which defeats the purpose of the backup in the first place...

Answer (score -1):

You could start a job `sp_start_job`. Within the job you execute a stored procedure where you execute the backup statement. I've done this already with a server trigger which is fired when a new database is created.