# Backing up database with trigger

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want backup data base with trigger. When I write this query

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
ON Table_1
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    BACKUP DATABASE test 
    TO DISK = 'C:\test.bak'  WITH DIFFERENTIAL,
    NAME = N'pcrm-Full Database Backup', 
    SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 50
GO
```

I get an error message:

> Msg 3021, Level 16, State 0, Procedure SPTEST, Line 6
>   Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SPTEST, Line 6
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Please help me

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server guru, but this error message seems to be saying that you can't call `BACKUP DATABASE` inside a trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use backup with triggers in SQL Server 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609119/how-to-use-backup-with-triggers-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Why would you want that anyway? back ups should be a part of a maintenance plan, not the result of data changes.

Comment: It looks like not much sense here - you are trying to backup with INSTEAD trigger, not even AFTER, so table becomes completely useless. Try use Maintenance plans (SSMS - Management - Maintenance plans) instead with complex backup plan - full at midnight, differential every 4 hours and log every 10 minutes (for example).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER test 
   ON  Table_1 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
        BACKUP DATABASE test TO DISK = N'C:\test.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'pcrm-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution?